# Phonegap push plugin stopped working after added crosswalk plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin, crosswalk

I'm developing using Ionic and i'm facing an odd problem, after i added crosswalk webview plugin my phonegap push plugin just stopped to work.

I got this "errors", if we can call them as that:

`ionic.cloud.min.js:6 Native: deviceready did not fire within 2000ms. This can happen when plugins are in an inconsistent state. Try removing plugins from plugins/ and reinstalling them.` 
`cordova.js:1223 deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.` 
`cordova.js:1216 Channel not fired: onCordovaInfoReady` 
`cordova.js:1216 Channel not fired: onFileSystemPathsReady` 
`ionic.cloud.min.js:6 Ionic Insights: Device information unavailable.` 
`index.html#/login:1 Deferred long-running timer task(s) to improve scrolling smoothness. See crbug.com/574343.`

And it just doesn't works anymore.

**Here is my cordova plugin list:**

> cordova plugins
>   cordova-plugin-compat 1.0.0 "Compat"
>   cordova-plugin-console 1.0.4 "Console"
>   cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 2.1.0 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
>   cordova-plugin-device 1.1.3 "Device"
>   cordova-plugin-file 4.3.0 "File"
>   cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.0 "Splashscreen"
>   cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.0 "StatusBar"
>   cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.0 "Whitelist"
>   ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
>   phonegap-plugin-push 1.9.0 "PushPlugin"

### ionic info

---

> Your system information:
>
> Cordova CLI: 6.4.0
>   Ionic Framework Version: 1.3.1
>   Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.4
>   Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.2
>   OS:
>   Node Version: v4.2.4
>
> --------------------------------

So basically this is it, without crosswalk plugin, the phonegap push plugin works, with it don't.

Hope someone can help me,

Thank you!

----------------------Edit

After some try and error, i'm thinking that's something related with scope when using crosswalk, because the $ionicPush.register() is not being fired.

What changes in $scope.$on("$ionicView.beforeEnter") using crosswalk?

Does this still working or crosswalk have their own "beforeEnter" as he is a diferente web view.

Attaching the images of console with ionic run android:

[Working without crosswalk:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfK4s.png)

[NOT Working with crosswalk:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7zdd.png)

As you can see in the line:

> Ionic Push: saved push token: dJYMPT2lVW8:APA91bE1UyH6qKksGykcbOFNe_HXVQPvAfSR7PJx_F_BgKIriE5sXpBGJENJS8heqQg7TAyKNAjp5sRjseEFoYIoz72DOY9VGq1-4dkKMMq6cIkhvLSBmxfKz57XBaFClEsUXpNp_zc2

The token isn't registered with crosswalk as it is without crosswalk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 2.1.0 of crosswalk plugin doesn't work with cordova-android 6.0.0 (the one included in cordova CLI 6.4.0)

Instead of downgrading you can install crosswalk from github that has already a fix for it

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my problem, for those who have the same problem than me, i need to downgrade cordova to 6.0.0 and push plugin to 1.8.3. Now everything works, hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

- Cordova 6.4.0
- Android platform 6
- phonegap-plugin-push 1.9.0

The same problem. To solve this i need to downgrade Android platform to 5.2.2, and phongap-plugin-push to 1.8.3.